# macでdockerを使うと遅いのでdocker-syncを入れたが上手く動かない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, docker, docker-compose

macでdocker-composeを使っています。起動等がかなり遅いのでdocker-syncを使おうとしたのですが
上手く動きません。解決法をご存知でしたら教えていただきたく。
以下が設定した内容です。

docker-compose.yml

```
hoge_web:
  container_name: hoge_web
  build: .
  command: ./script/start
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
    - 6379:6379
  volumes:
    - volume-sync:/usr/local/hoge:nocopy
    - ../gems:/hoge_gems
  links:
    - hoge_db

hoge_db:
  container_name:hoge _db
  image: mysql
  volumes:
    - ../mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: hoge_development
    MYSQL_USER: hoge
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: hoge
  ports:
    - 3306

hoge_web:
  volumes:
    volume-sync:
      external: true
```

docker-sync.yml

```
version: "2"

syncs:
  volume-sync:
    src: ../hoge
```

実行時に出たエラーです。

```
hoge-74noMacBook-Pro:docker$ docker-sync start
          ok  Starting native_osx for sync volume-sync
     success  Sync container started
     success  Starting Docker-Sync in the background
hoge-74noMacBook-Pro:docker$ docker-compose up --build
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
hoge_web.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

バージョンは以下になります。

```
hoge-74noMacBook-Pro:docker$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e
hoge-74noMacBook-Pro:docker$ docker -v
Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72
hoge-74noMacBook-Pro:docker$ docker-sync -v
0.4.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

末尾の

```
  volumes:
    volume-sync:
      external: true
```

が`hoge_web:`以下にありますが、この`volumes`はdocker-compose.ymlのトップレベルにあるべきものではないですか？

Comment: トップレベルに持ってくると違うエラーが出て動かない感じです。ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for volumes: 'volume-sync'

Comment: そういやdocker-compose.ymlのバージョンが指定されてないようですがv2以降でないと`volumes`使えないやつではなかったでしたっけ……ドキュメント読んだ感じ。(といってもこのバージョンのcomposeでv1そもそもサポートされてないような気もしますが) https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-1

Comment: docker-syncを使用しなければバージョン指定しなくてもvolumes使えます。docker-syncとdocker-compose.ymlにバージョン指定するとバージョンが合ってないエラーが出るようです。。。

Comment: あ、言い方が悪かったですね、トップレベルのvolumesのことです。

Comment: バージョン指定したら動きました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

docker-syncの解決方法では無いですが、以下のcachedオプションをつけることで速くなりました。

```
volumes:
  - ../hoge:/usr/local/hoge:cached
  - ../gems:/hoge_gems:cached
```